# Remove backward slashes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string and i want to remove all backslahes.

```
$str = esktop rch for \\\\\\\\\\\\\'lorem ipsum\\\\\\\\\\\\' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolv.
```

In PHP

```
preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $str ); is working.
```

How to do that same in javascript ???

Comment: Is `$str` valid string syntax

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\\\\/g, '');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example:

```js
var someString = 'sktop rch for \\\\\\\\\\\\\lorem ipsum\\\\\\\\\\\\ will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolv';
var anotherString = someString.replace(/\\/g, '');
document.write(anotherString);
```